# Python re: how to concatenate string and dict values in a re-sub repl_string?

Tags: python, python-re

I have a string:

```
mytext = 'Here a text:<text id="myid1">Hello</text>. Here another: <text class="myclass">Bye</text>. And a third one: <text  id="myid2">Cheers</text>'
```

I'd like to replace each `<text id="myid">XXXX</text>` according to a dict:

```
names = {
  "Hello": "this is hello",
  "Bye": "this is good bye",
  "Cheers": "this is cheers"
}
```

I would like to replace them like:

```
new_mytext = 'Here a text:<text>this is hello</text>. Here another: <text>this is bye</text>. And a third one: <text>this is cheers</text>'
```

I'm trying:

```
re.sub("<text(.*?)>(.*?)<\/text>", "<text\\1>\\2<\/text>", "mytext")
```

instead of `\\2`I need something like `name["\2"]`, but this doesn't work.
How can I get the values of my dict from inside the er.sub format? Or do you recommend another method?

Answer (score 2):

Almost there, the trick would be to put the whole match object in groups:

```py
res=mytext
for el in re.finditer("(<text.*?>)(.*?)(<\/text>)", mytext):
    res=res.replace(el[0], ''.join([el[1], names.get(el[2], el[2]), el[3]]))
```

Outputs:

```py
Here a text:<text id="myid1">this is hello</text>. Here another: <text class="myclass">this is good bye</text>. And a third one: <text  id="myid2">this is cheers</text>
```

Comment: Nice. You don't even need groups for `<text>` and `</text>` but use string literals instead. Makes it even more transparent (but also less generic of course).